# не работают параметры при вызове bridge.send

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Есть функция

```
async executeMethod() {
    try {
        let response = await bridge.send(method[this.state.section].name, this.state.params)

        window.responseAPI = response
        this.props.openModal('viewResponse')
    } catch(err) {
        window.responseAPI = err
        this.props.openModal('viewResponse')
    }
}
```

значение this.state.params берется из textarea. При вызове функции возникает ошибка об отсутствии параметров или об их невалидности. Подскажите, как можно это исправить, чтобы параметры учитывались

Answer (score 0):

Второй параметр в bridge.send должен быть [объектом](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vkontakte/vk-bridge).

Если `this.state.params` берется из textarea, то скорей всего это строка с JSON. тогда надо выполнить преобразование к объекту.

```js
let response = await bridge.send(method[this.state.section].name, JSON.parse(this.state.params))
```